# How to use Eunit:test() generate a xml file which include some compling info

Tags: xml, erlang, eunit

I have some erlang file(.erl).And I compile them. Now I want to use some function to generate a xml which is about the compling info of these files.

Here is a address,
http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/eunit.pdf

In this pdf,There is a function eunit:test/2 which can generate a xml file.

eunit:test([fib, eunit_examples],
[{report,{eunit_surefire,[{dir,"."}]}}]).

But i don't know these parameters represent. I just know fib = modulename  dir = generate location.What about eunit_examples？ ,report？ ,eunit_surefire？

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure this is the function you are looking for. Eunit is a testing framework, and thus the function

```
eunit:test(...).
```

will give you information about any testing functions you have written within the modules.

---

If indeed you are looking to generate reports on those tests, in XML format, you simply use the form:

```
eunit:test([MODULES], [{report, {eunit_surefire, [{dir, "."}]}}]).
```

where `MODULES` is a list of any modules you want to do testing of, and everything else stays the same (for example, `fib` and `eunit_examples` are the two modules that are being tested in the example you gave.)

The `report` atom says that you want to generate a report, and the `eunit_surefire` atom says what format to generate the report with. I'm not sure there are any other ways to generate the reports with XML besides using `eunit_surefire`.

Comment: Oh thank you! It's very useful to me.I tried, it really works.And it generated a xml file. But I just got other questions. 1.Are there some other atoms can instead of "report",and generate a xml file which include other useful info?  2. If I want to generate other format, are there some other words I can use.

Comment: It doesn't look like there are any other atoms that can be used to generate other data. `report` is all you've got, and it doesn't look like there are any other formats you can use, either. Sorry!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11340812/113848) has an example of an alternative report module implementation.