# how to generate unit test result in xml using rebar

Tags: xml, rebar

I need to run the unit testing with rebar , after executing , I need generate the test result xml file.

I know , by default , rebar can generate html file.
**1. Is there some parameters to control the rebar to loading the unit testing result in xml ?**
or some other way to make xml file by rebar ?

not limit in rebar,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
or using some other test tool to run the eunit test, meanwhile , generate the xml file .

for example , in .Net after compiling , we can use MSTest.exe , Nunit.exe(or other tool) to schedule the testing, getting trx file by MSTest.exe , getting xml file Nunit file by Nunit.exe

here , I want to know,

**2.is there some tools to run the unit test and loading the result into xml like these ways ?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720919/how-to-use-eunittest-generate-a-xml-file-which-include-some-compling-info and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027351/getting-test-results-from-eunit-in-erlang .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using eunit, put `{eunit_opts, [verbose, {report,{eunit_surefire,[{dir,"."}]}}]}.` into your rebar.config.  This generates a surefire compatible xml output that is parseable by a number of plugins and tools.