# Getting test results from Eunit in Erlang

Tags: erlang, eunit

I am working with Erlang and EUnit to do unit tests, and I would like to write a test runner to automate the running of my unit tests. The problem is that eunit:test/1 seems to only return "error" or "ok" and not a list of tests and what they returned in terms of what passed or failed.

So is there a way to run tests and get back some form of a data structure of what tests ran and their pass/fail state?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using rebar you don't have to implement your own runner. You can simply run:

```
rebar eunit
```

Rebar will compile and run all tests in the `test` directory (as well as eunit tests inside your modules). Furthermore, rebar allows you set the same options in the `rebar.config` as in the shell:

```
{eunit_opts, [verbose, {report,{eunit_surefire,[{dir,"."}]}}]}.
```

You can use these options also in the shell:

```
> eunit:test([foo], [verbose, {report,{eunit_surefire,[{dir,"."}]}}]).
```

See also documentation for [verbose option](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/eunit.html#test-2) and [structured report](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/eunit_surefire.html).

An alternative option would be to use Common Test instead of Eunit. Common Test comes with a runner (`ct_run` command) and gives you more flexibility in your test setup but is also a little more complex to use. Common Test lacks on the available macros but produces very comprehensible html reports.

Answer (score 8):

No easy or documented way, but there are currently two ways you can do this. One is to give the option 'event_log' when you run the tests:

```
eunit:test(my_module, [event_log])
```

(this is undocumented and was really only meant for debugging). The resulting file "eunit-events.log" is a text file that can be read by Erlang using file:consult(Filename).

The more powerful way (and not really all that difficult) is to implement a custom event listener and give it as an option to eunit:

```
eunit:test(my_module, [{report, my_listener_module}])
```

This isn't documented yet, but it ought to be. A listener module implements the eunit_listener behaviour (see src/eunit_listener.erl). There are only five callback functions to implement. Look at src/eunit_tty.erl and src/eunit_surefire.erl for examples.

Answer (score 3):

I've just pushed to GitHub a very trivial listener, which stores the EUnit results in a DETS table. This can be useful, if you need to further process those data, since they're stored as Erlang terms in the DETS table.

https://github.com/prof3ta/eunit_terms

Example of usage:

```
> eunit:test([fact_test], [{report,{eunit_terms,[]}}]).
All 3 tests passed.
ok
> {ok, Ref} = dets:open_file(results).
{ok,#Ref<0.0.0.114>}
> dets:lookup(Ref, testsuite).
[{testsuite,<<"module 'fact_test'">>,8,<<>>,3,0,0,0,
        [{testcase,{fact_test,fact_zero_test,0,0},[],ok,0,<<>>},
         {testcase,{fact_test,fact_neg_test,0,0},[],ok,0,<<>>},
         {testcase,{fact_test,fact_pos_test,0,0},[],ok,0,<<>>}]}]
```

Hope this helps.